# URL / Permalink to a linkedIn share created via UGC post api?

Tags: linkedin-api

How can I get url or permalink to a LinkedIn share created via UGC post API? I have looked all over the internet and have not been successful.

Comment: Please show us the pieces of code that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a ugcPost you will receive a 201 response where the response body includes a reference to your post in the format `urn:li:ugcPost:123456`.

Append this reference to `https://linkedin.com/feed/update` resulting in the URL:

`https://linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:upgcPost:123456`